# Repeated nextval on the same sequence => ORA-01000 maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a PL/SQL procedure which includes:

```
PROCEDURE ElementCompound(

   ....

   SELECT MY_BASE.SEQ_MY_TABKE.NEXTVAL INTO batchKey FROM DUAL;

   ....

END RegisterCompound;
```

This is called multiple times from the same session in a loop from a Java application:

```
   for (InputObject registerObject : registerObjectList) {
    // THE INSTRUCTION THAT MAKE THE CALL 
            List<Object> results = (List<Object>) **databaseUtil.executePlsqlPackage**(connection,
                    plSqlCallData.getPackageCallInstruction().get(), plsqlPackageParams, colOut, colType);
    }
```

After 100 runs of this loop, it throws this error:

```
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
```

I reproduced this error in SQL Developer by running simple SQL instructions.

I created a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  SEQUENCE_TEST  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 2006680770 CACHE 500  NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

and then ran multiple times (many times - more than 100) the `nextval` instruction on this sequence:

```
SELECT SEQUENCE_TEST.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;
```

And I obtain the same error:

```
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
```

First, I would understand what is happening. Is it an implicit cursor that opens when I run `nextval`? Or it is something else?

Second, I want to modify my code to avoid such an error. I do not want to increase the number of allowed open cursors, so how can I fix it?

Comment: What version is your Oracle database? Also, please share the problematic code that is causing the error.  There could be something else you are doing in your code that is causing the error.

Comment: Can you reproduce your simple case in SQL\*Plus, or does it only occur in SQL Developer? How many times do you have to call nextval - what is 'many'? And you haven't shown one, but are you using a database link?

Comment: The reason I asked if it was only SQL Developer is because there was a cursor issue with reused statement in one of the JDBC driver versions. (12.1.0.2; see MoS Doc ID 2188724.1, though may well not be relevant!) That's why the versions you are using is important. If your real problem is also over JDBC that *might* be a culprit, but you could still be doing something else wrong in the Java side - like creating a new statement for each call and never closing them.

Comment: *"The "loop" i talked is in fact a Java application that call multiple times with the same session the following procedure"* So the problem is how your Java code is calling the procedure. You need to post that code too. Also, please use markup when posting code: the SO editor ignores embedded HTML tags like `<code>`

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks a lot. I do not write the java code. But what isee in the Java code, is 1 connection taken from the (Hikari) connections pool, mulitple call of the procedure i talked in my post, a commit and then a close of the connection (in fact the connection go again to the connection pool). I will try to see more the Java code to see if the problem is here. I belived that it was in SQL because i reproduce, but now, as i know the problem with SQL Developer, i am not certain. Thanks Alex.

Comment: The real call is here : databaseUtil.executePlsqlPackage. It is this instruction.

Comment: You might need to look into what `databaseUtil.executePlsqlPackage` does, particularly if it creates a statement but doesn't close it - relying on the connection closure to clean up, perhaps. (I'm not saying there *is* a problem with SQL Developer, or the JDBC driver; just throwing out possibilities...)

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks Alex for your help. You are right. It creates a statement but does not close it immediatly. The Java comment indicates that it must not be closed. But you give me a very good path to find the cause of the problem. I do not write this code, i have not to change, but i will try to find a solution. I will inform you as soon a good solution will be find. Thanks a lot Alex.

Comment: Alex. A big Thanks. You have found the solution. I use the decorator pattern to make exactly the same thing that the executePlsqlPackage method of databaseUtil makes, but i add just this instruction : i close the statement. Like you say to me.Because, if i do not make this, the error ORA-01000 in 1 of every two cases.  A BIG THANKS Alex. But i have now another problem : i am a noob in stackoverflow and i don't know how i can mark that YOU solve my problem. How can i do this ? Thansk man and have a very nice day.

Comment: @Alex maybe you have to answer because that's YOU who find the solution (NOT me). And after, maybe it's a way that i put this answer as the solution ? That's what i want to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex and APC. The problem was first in the Java code and not in the PL/SQL code.